# Infinte vertical scroll for a HTML table

Tags: html, css, angular

For Html table, Vertical Infinite scroll should come.

Please find the controller code here, 
This is my controller code.
If u need any other details please let me know 
Thanks in advance , 
So here I need the infinte vertical scroll.
when I scroll the down it show show records till the end, but right now it is showing only 10 records

```
onScrolled(event) {
        if (event && event.srcElement) {
            const scrollHeight = event.srcElement.scrollHeight;
            const scrollTop = event.srcElement.scrollTop;
            const offsetHeight = event.srcElement.offsetHeight;
            if (offsetHeight + scrollTop >= scrollHeight && this.allowAPICall && !this.completeDataLoaded) {
                const accountIds = this.getAccounts();
                this.initializeLoadTransactions(accountIds, this.selectedFilters.type);
            }
        }
        this.sortingColumn = [];
    }
```

This is the CSS code and I have done below changes 
but I am unable to get the infinite vertical scroll. 
Here I have done with tran-table for the infinite scroll to a HTML table

```css
table {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(240, 240, 240), rgb(250, 250, 250));
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  th {
    color: blue;
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 15px;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
  }
  tbody tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
    td {
      padding: 25px 0px 25px 15px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border-top: 0;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
  }
}

.table thead th {
  vertical-align: initial !important;
}

.transDetailsRecord {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.tran-table::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

.tran-table::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}
```

```html
This is the HTML code and done below changes but I am unable to get the Infinte vertical scroll Here I have done with transtable for Infinte scroll to a html table

<div class="transDetailsRecord">
  <table class="table ">
    <caption class="sr-only">Your Transactions</caption>
    <thead>
      <th (click)="transactionSorting('date');">
        Date <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('date')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th (click)="transactionSorting('accountId');">
        Account #<i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('accountId')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th (click)="transactionSorting('accountNickName');">
        Account Nickname<i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('accountNickName')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th (click)="transactionSorting('transaction');">
        Transaction Type <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('transaction')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th (click)="transactionSorting('symbolcusip');">
        Symbol/CUSIP <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('symbolcusip')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th (click)="transactionSorting('description');">
        Description <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('description')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th (click)="transactionSorting('heldin');">
        Held In <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('heldin')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th (click)="transactionSorting('quantity');">
        Qty <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('quantity')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th (click)="transactionSorting('price');">
        Price <i class="fa" [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('price')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th (click)="transactionSorting('amount');">
        Value ($) <i [ngClass]="sortingIconClass('amount')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
    </thead>

    <tbody *ngIf="loading || error || noData">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="10" style="
            text-align: center" *ngIf="loading">
          <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
          <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="10" style="
            text-align: center" *ngIf="error">
          <ngb-alert [dismissible]="false" type="danger">{{errorMessage}}</ngb-alert>
        </td>
        <td colspan="10" style="
            text-align: center" *ngIf="noData">
          <ngb-alert [dismissible]="false" type="info">No transactions available</ngb-alert>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody class="tran-table" *ngIf="transactions?.length > 0 && !loading && !error && !noData" (scroll)="onScrolled($event);">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let t of transactions">
        <tr>
          <td>{{t.date?.format('MM/DD/YYYY')}}</td>
          <td>{{t.accountNumber | maskAccountno: maskAccountNo}}</td>
          <td>{{t.accountNickName}}</td>
          <td>{{t.transaction}}</td>
          <td>{{t.symbolcusip}}</td>
          <td>{{t.description | titlecase}}</td>
          <td>{{t.heldin}}</td>
          <td>{{t.quantity}}</td>
          <td>{{t.price | currency}}</td>
          <td>{{t.amount | currency}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="t.showRealizedData">
          <th>Puchase Date</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Unit Cost($)</th>
          <th>Cost Basis($)</th>
          <th>Price($)</th>
          <th>Value($)</th>
          <th>Short term<br>Gain/Loss($)</th>
          <th style="border-right: 0;">Long term<br>Gain/Loss($)</th>
          <th style="width: 12%;border-right: 0;">
            <img class="icon mr-3" title="Export CSV" *ngIf="t.subTransactions?.length > 0" (click)="download('text/csv')" src="./assets/images/export_CSV.png" />
          </th>
        </tr>
        <ng-container *ngIf="t.showRealizedData">
          <tr *ngIf="subTableLoading || subTableError || subTableNoData">
            <td *ngIf="subTableLoading">
              <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
              <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="subTableError">
              <ngb-alert [dismissible]="false" type="danger">{{errorMessage}}</ngb-alert>
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="subTableNoData">
              <ngb-alert [dismissible]="false" type="info">No transactions available</ngb-alert>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <ng-container *ngIf="!subTableLoading && !subTableError && !subTableNoData">
            <tr *ngFor="let st of t.subTransactions;let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'sub-table-last-row': t.subTransactions.length-1 === i}">
              <td><span class="t-sub-cell1">{{st.acquisitionDate
                                | date : 'MMM d, y'}}</span></td>
              <td><span class="t-sub-cell1">{{st.quantity}}</span></td>
              <td><span class="t-sub-cell1">{{st.avgCostIndicator}}</span></td>
              <td><span class="t-sub-cell1">{{st.adjustedCost}}</span></td>
              <td><span class="t-sub-cell1">{{st.purchaseCost}}</span></td>
              <td><span class="t-sub-cell1">{{st.soldValue}}</span></td>
              <td><span class="t-sub-cell1">{{st.shortTermGainLoss}}</span></td>
              <td style="border-right: 0;"><span class="t-sub-cell1">{{st.longTermGainLoss}}</span></td>
            </tr>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
      <tr *ngIf="!allowAPICall">
        <td>
          <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
          <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more details about your problem. Because the controller code is not here. So unable to get the whole problem statement.

Comment: here is the controlller code :

Comment: Simply create plunkr or jsfiddle. So anyone will get an idea.

Comment: So far how many records you have now? Are you having more than 10 records?

Comment: Yes I am having more than 10 records. But at present it is showing only 10 records... It need to show more than 10 records when I scroll down ..
Please help me in this . Thanks in advance

Comment: @SandeepRockzz , the scroll event will work only when your section is having **scrollable items already**. Means your UI is having already records as like scrollable then only scroll will work. Otherwise, it will not work. Please create UI having scrollable records and then try.